# Socket.io server not receiving custom headers send from socket.io client connection

Tags: javascript, socket.io, socket.io-client

Below is my code to make socket connection by using socket.io. The problem with the following code is I am not able to get customer header set  with extraHeaders at server  end. Nether `socket.request.headers` nor socket.handshake.headers` works for me.

```
const socketIO = require("socket.io-client");
    
const socket = socketIO('wss://domain.com', {
          transports: ["websocket"],
          extraHeaders: {
            
            build_number: "227"
          }
        });
    
        socket.on("connect", () => {
          console.log("connected");
        });
```

Comment: for me when I remove` transports: ["web socket"]` it worked. But I am not really satisfied with this approach.

Comment: [_"In a browser environment, the extraHeaders option will be ignored if you only enable the WebSocket transport, since the WebSocket API in the browser does not allow providing custom headers."_](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#extraheaders). Are you using your code in a browser?

Comment: I am using it for mobile and web. mobile works and in web got problem

Comment: The message (and page) I posted explains why.

Comment: meaning no fix for web with transports: ["websocket"]

Comment: That's correct.